# Calculating Speed based off of BPM

Tags: objective-c, math

I'm trying to make notes fly across the screen. The notes would be in 1/16th of a beat, and the BPM can be set to any positive integer.

Right now, my equation is `distance(in pixels) * (BPM / 60s) * deltaTime`, where deltaTime is the time between frames. On paper, it makes sense. However, when I run the app the notes fly by way too slow. Assuming `10 BPM` and a `deltaTime` average of `0.06255s` and a distance of `750px`, `750px * (10BPM/60s) * 0.06255s` means I should travel `~8px` a frame(@60FPS), so after 1 second I should travel `470px`.

Instead, I am traveling much slower. After `20` seconds of running, the notes only stepped `250px`!

Code for calculating time between frames

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    deltaBeatTime += currentTime - previousFrameTime;
    CFTimeInterval deltaTime = currentTime - previousFrameTime;
    previousFrameTime = currentTime;

    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", deltaBeatTime];
    [beat moveBeat:deltaTime];
  }
```

Moves the beat according to the BPM

```
-(void) moveBeat:(float)timeInterval
{
    float spaceMoved = (container.getBeatSpeed / 60.0f) * (750.0f) * (timeInterval);
    pixels += spaceMoved;
    dt += timeInterval;
    NSLog(@"%f in %f", pixels, dt);
    [self setPosition:CGPointMake(self.position.x - spaceMoved, self.position.y)];
}
```

Is there an error with my equation, or am I forgetting to scale by some factor?

Comment: My guess would be something is wrong with your timeInterval, or how often update: is called.

Comment: Update is called 60 times a second (assuming 60fps).

Comment: If you have ~60fps you should have an average deltaTime of about 0.016s not 0.063s, but that is not enough to explain the discrepancy you see. Is `currentTime` recomputed at every call to `update` ? What kind of timer/time resolution do you have ? Can you post the log from the `moveBeat` function ?